# Subversion Repositories on OSX are getting built with different permissionsw

Tags: svn, mac-osx

I'm running subversion on Snow Leopard.

I created a repository and I, and others on the local network can access it just fine via HTTP to my local machine.

I created a new repository and others on the LAN can access it, but are denied permission to commit anything.

Everything appears the same (conf files for both have the exact same users/pwds). So I started looking at the permissions locally in OSX.

I found that the file permissions for the repository that works look like this:

```
_www : read & write
_www : read only
everyone : read only
```

On the one that's denying commits, the file permissions look like this:

```
system: read & write
_www : read only
everyone : read only
```

I created both repositories via:

```
sudo svnadmin create /path/to/my/repository
```

Any theories as to why they are being created with different file permissions?

SOLUTION:

Probably not ideal, but I can just manually grant _www read and write permissions recursively easy enough via the finder (the ol' 777 hammer). Still, I'm curious as to what I may have done that would have caused the permissions to be different in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Check your umask in terminal:

```
umask
```

If it is 022, by default only owner gets write access, group / world is read only.

Here are instruction how to change it:

http://www.pyrosoft.co.uk/blog/2009/02/19/changing-the-default-umask-on-osx-leopards/

Also please be aware that allowing by default write access has security implications ...